# Script is working too much, max_execution_time fail

Tags: php, email

I added new feature on my site. User uploading archive with rent receipts (~100 users so 100 files) in pdf format. 1 file is ~25 kb, hole archive is ~2.5-2.7mb.

I wrote script. Script saves archive, opens it, unpack images to another folder and sending e-mail for each image (to each user). It takes time. I tested it in my localserver (`max_execution_time 60`) and it fail, because script worked too much time. After that I checked my hosting `max_execution_time`... Well, now I am sad.

I have next structure atm:

1. Draw form
2. Upload archive with php (`/MM-YYYY\.(zip|rar)` format) (+ all checks etc)
3. Making ajax request, sending month + year
4. On this script I get month + year (so get path) and after that I do next sequence:

   Get user e-mail from bd (file names in archive are `/[1-9][0-9]*\.pdf/` (1.pdf, 100.pdf, 555.pdf etc), sending e-mail to user with attachment.

Seems to me it takes time to send mail with attach. I have 50-100 mails.

1) How I can speed up script or how I approach to this have to be changed?

2) Is it okay that 50 mails with attachements sending so slowly?

Help please. Thank you.

**ADD — Time Tests**

14.9609 s. - 5 files; 
3.6962 s. - 1 file; 
14.2918 - 4 files (1st try);
 
14.1198 - 4 files (2nd try); 
35.271 - 10 files
35.811 - 10 files (another try);

**ADD — I tried another way : many ajax requests instead of one**

I changed approach to send e-mails. I do all actions in 2-nd item of the list. In page which is requested by ajax I only send e-mail. Results are next :

Sending 1 e-mail: 
[image: 1 e-mail] 

its ok

Sending 3 e-mails:
[image: 3 e-mails]
what?? 9.82 for 1 mail?? why not 3.5?

Sending 10 e-mails:
[image: 10 e-mails]
?!?!!@#!@% 18.16 for 1st e-mail. Seems to me this can not be called 'async'. Why it takes so much time.

So : time of 1 ajax request to page which send 10 e-mails is equal to 10 ajax request's to page which send 1 e-mail ???

I thought 10 ajax requests will be send asynchronously and it will take 3-4 seconds for work. Can anybody explain it ? :(

Comment: "How I can speed up script" - Profile it and find out where the slow-downs are happening.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Is it okay that 50 mails with attachements sending so slowly?

Comment: Is it normal? :) Ok 1 minute, I will check execution time with 1-5 files.

Comment: 14.9609 s. - 5 files; 3.6962 s. - 1 file; 14.2918 - 4 f. (1st try); 14.1198 - 4 f. (2nd try); 35.271 - 10 files

Answer (score 0):

If you feel the mailing part is the one that causes the delay, you can break it down.

Set up a cron job to the mailings for you. The smallest frequency is one minute.

Also, you can increase the execution time.
However, certain web hosts have strict policies and will not be favorable to you depending on how long each process would go (I assume this will increase as you add more users and files) and how many times it occurs during a 24 hour period.

My recommendation is to use a cron job as long as you are confident that your coding is efficient.

Also, can you not CC or BCC the mail? TBH, I am not sure if the mail sending time would increase. Just a small thought.